# extracting data from a no API website / jsoup / android / beginner

Tags: android, networking, web-scraping, jsoup

am new to the android/coding world , i have learned android basics and now i got into networking , i have a somehow clear idea of parsing json data from websites that has an api
so for my learning project i want to implement the whole subscene website in android app in my own way from the search engine to downloading srt files.... so after googling it i came across the jsoup library but online articles and jsoup.org documentation didnt help cuz am new to the whole thing and the concept of elements,classes,tables,nodes .... is confusing for me so :

1. is there an api for the subscene website ?
2. do i have to learn html and dom in order to use jsoup ?
3. is there any beginner friendly tutorial to learn jsoup ?
4. is there any better way to get real time changing data from websites with no api ?

dont mind my badly asked question cuz am new to asking questions online too

Answer (score 0):

1. Google it
2. Absolutely
3. with no html knowledge? Very unlikely
4. No

I'd suggest you start with a simpler project :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers bro !!  Do i need to learn all the html , dom ,css concepts ?? Or there are specific just specific things to learn ?

Comment: you need to have a general understanding of html dom and css selectors. The specifics you can always google.

Comment: Its rather simple actually